# find with -type -regex and -prune

Tags: regex, bash

I have a set of directories (in the current directory) into which I am sorting files. The source files are either in the current directory or in other directories (often many levels deep) which it also contains.

I'm getting list of files to process with find, excluding files in the destination directories with -type -regex and -prune, and selecting the files with another -regex.

At least, that's what I am intending and the list of files is correct - with one exception: the destination directories appear in the list (but not the files they already contain - which is the desired behaviour).

I have a workaround: in the subsequent loop I am discarding anything that's not a file.

I am sure that there's either a simple error in the directory exclusion regex *or* I am missing the point of what -prune is supposed to do.

Here's my code (I am using a Mac - hence the -E option):

```
find -E . \
-type d -regex './(DVD|quarantine|720|high|low|error)' -prune -o \
-type f -regex '.*.(avi|wmv|mp4|m4v|mov|mkv)'
```

... and one final question: how do I make the file selection regex case *insensitive*?

Comment: GNU find has the option `-iregex` which is like `-regex` but case insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of the `find` man page:

```
 -print  This primary always evaluates to true.  It prints the pathname of the current file to standard output.  If
         none of -exec, -ls, -print, -print0, or -ok is specified, the given expression shall be effectively replaced
         by ( given expression ) -print.
```

So, because your command line had none of `-exec`, `-ls`, `-print`, `-print0`, or `-ok` specified, it was the same as if your command had been:

```
find -E . \
\( -type d -regex './(DVD|quarantine|720|high|low|error)' -prune -o \
   -type f -regex '.*.(avi|wmv|mp4|m4v|mov|mkv)' \) -print
```

The solution is an explicit `-print` (or `-print0`) on the right side of `-o`:

```
find -E . \
-type d -regex './(DVD|quarantine|720|high|low|error)' -prune -o \
-type f -regex '.*\.(avi|wmv|mp4|m4v|mov|mkv)' -print
```

Also, as mentioned in a comment the regular expressions can be made case insensitive by using `-iregex`.

<s>Or, if you wish, you can also embed case insensitivity in the expressions themselves (see the `re_format` man page):</s>

```
find -E . \
-type d -regex './(?i:DVD|quarantine|720|high|low|error)' -prune -o \
-type f -regex '.*\.(?i:avi|wmv|mp4|m4v|mov|mkv)' -print
```

EDIT: no, `-iregex` is the only way to achieve case insensitivity.

Comment: Thank you.  That explains my misunderstanding very well.

Comment: I've run into a problem.  I used the embedded case insensitivity just in the file selection part and I get this error: find: -regex: .*\.(?i:avi|wmv|mp4|m4v|mov|mkv): repetition-operator operand invalid

Comment: Using -iregex fixed it.  Perhaps it's another mac-related thing?

Comment: @Lorccan Ah, I misread the `re_format` man page. The `(?i:....)` construct is only for "enhanced extended" regular expressions, whereas `-E` just enables "extended" regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks.  Good to know reason.